# Using ngf-select to try and capture from the device camera (Android)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, camera, ng-file-upload

I am have a cordova mobile application runnning Cordova 6.5.0 and I am trying to get the ability to capture images from the camera & upload in my mobile app using ngf-upload.
https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I have tried using ngf-capture="'camera'" & ngf-capture="'other'" and all this seems to do is open up the default 'Recent' files file manager application where I can select files instead of opening the camera??

Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
        <div>
            <input ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)"
               ngf-fix-orientation="true"
               ngf-capture="'other'"
               ngf-accept="'image/*'"
               ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)"
               ngf-keep="true">
            </input>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same. Did you managed to find a resolution for this?

Comment: @AndrewEbling I didnt unfortunately ended up using cordova plugins and using the camera functionality there - did you manage to get it working with ngf-select?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but will look into it again in the new year when I will be restarting work on the project.